react hook form + yup. The form with the file
I have two fields name and preview. I have done validation for these fields (code below), but an error is returned to me when I add a file to the preview (error that I have to fill in this field)
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    name: Yup.string().required('Enter name'),
    preview: Yup.mixed().test('required', 'You need to provide a file', (file) => {
        if (file) return true
        return false
    }),
})

interface AddCategoryProps {}

export default function AddCategory({}: AddCategoryProps) {
const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {},
        mode: 'onChange',
        resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
    })

    const onSubmit = handleSubmit(({ name, preview }) => {
        console.log({ name, preview })
    })

    return (
        <section className={styles.wrapper}>

            <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className={styles.form}>
                <AdminFormInput
                    register={register}
                    registerName='name'
                    errorText={errors.name?.message}
                    isError={Boolean(errors.name?.message)}
                    label='Name'
                />
                <AdminFormInput
                    register={register}
                    registerName='preview'
                    errorText={errors.preview?.message}
                    isError={Boolean(errors.preview?.message)}
                    label='Preview'
                    isFile={true}
                    previewText='Select file'
                />
                <AdminFormButton />
            </form>
        </section>
    )

}

// AdminFormInput //

import { useRef } from 'react'
import styles from './AdminFormInput.module.sass'
import { FieldValues, Path, UseFormRegister } from 'react-hook-form'

interface AdminFormInputProps<T extends FieldValues> {
    label: string
    isFile?: boolean
    previewText?: string
    isSelect?: boolean

    registerName: Path<T>
    register: UseFormRegister<T>
    isError: boolean
    errorText: string | undefined
}

export const AdminFormInput = <T extends FieldValues>({
    label,
    isFile,
    previewText,
    isSelect,
    registerName,
    register,
    isError,
    errorText,
}: AdminFormInputProps<T>) => {
    const fileRef = useRef<any>()

    return (
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
            <label className={styles.title}>{label}</label>
            {!isFile && !isSelect && (
                <>
                    <input {...register(registerName)} type='text' className={styles.input} />
                    {isError && <span className={styles.error}>{errorText}</span>}
                </>
            )}

            {isFile && (
                <>
                    <input
                        {...register(registerName)}
                        type='file'
                        accept='image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg'
                        hidden
                        ref={fileRef}
                    />
                    <div className={styles.file} onClick={() => fileRef.current.click()}>
                        {previewText}
                    </div>
                    {isError && <span className={styles.error}>{errorText}</span>}
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default AdminFormInput

I tried to do this, but when I click on the submit button of the form, the name field is filled in, but the preview field remains undefined
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    name: Yup.string().required('Введите название категории'),
    preview: Yup.mixed()
    }),
})

Actually, the problem is that the preview field does not include the file that I select
